# Update singel cell of a row in an SQLite database on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I wont to update a single cell of a row in the database. However the row contains of 5 columns so and i would like to not passing all the other values as well as they should remain the same.

I have this code snippet:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(STATION_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        //If the database already include some stations.
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            ContentValues stationValues = new ContentValues();

            for(StopLocation station: stations)
            {
                stationValues.clear();

                //The database already includes the station
                if(cursor.getString(POS_STA_ID).equals(station.getId()))
                {
                    values.put(KEY_STA_DISTANCE, "null");

                    db.update(STATION_TABLE, stationValues, KEY_STA_ID + "=?", new String[]{station.getId()});
                }
```

The db.update method throws this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly and assuming you are always dealing with one row, there are two possible ways to approach this:

**First:**

Get the values of all fields in the entire row, and declare them as content values before updating:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Field1","123");
cv.put("Field2","True")
```

**Second:**

Use execSQL() method:

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE your_table SET Field1 = foo WHERE POST_STA_ID = "+ station.getId();
myDataBase.execSQL(strSQL);
```

Comment: I am trying with this call but it doesn't look like anything gets updaterd. Any clues? `UPDATE Stations SET distance=NULL WHERE distance!=NULL`

Comment: I found a solution. I should use IS NOT NULL in stead of !=NULL